# No recibo la información del hash params Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Estoy usando Devise, quiero traer un dato del formulario de registro de usuario para posteriormente hacer una consulta en la BD para ver si existe, al momento de ejecutar la validación nunca recibo el valor del params[:contrato]. Aquí les dejo el código de mi controlador (el que se encarga de la validación):

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    validate_code
  end

  private

  def validate_code
    # Agrega tu lógica de validación de código aquí.
    if !Contrato.exists?(codigo: params[:contrato])
        flash[:notice] = 'El código de contrato no existe'
        redirect_to '/users/sign_up'
    else
        @cliente = User.new(usuario_params)
        @cliente.save
        flash[:notice] = 'Usuario creado exitosamente'
        redirect_to '/'
    end
  end

  def usuario_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:nombre,:apellido,:cargo,:telefono,:direccion,:contrato,:compania,:fluido,:solido,:ambiente,:email,:password,:password_confirmation,:user_type)
  end
end
```

y este es una porción del formulario de registro (new.html.erb)

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :contrato %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :contrato, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "contrato" %>
  </div>
```

[image]

como se puede observar en la imagen, si nos ubicamos en la consola, en la consulta para ser mas especifico, no esta el valor que debería recibir en params[:contrato]

Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que debería ser:

```
Contrato.exists?(codigo: usuario_params[:contrato])
```

---

Se usa `usuario_params` para usar el método que tienes definido al final de tu controlador.

```
  def usuario_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:nombre,:apellido,:cargo,:telefono,:direccion,:contrato,:compania,:fluido,:solido,:ambiente,:email,:password,:password_confirmation,:user_type)
  end
```

que este a su vez se crea para usar [strong parameters](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters), que es la forma que dispone rails para validar los parámetros a venir en un request.
Quizás para este caso en particular no tiene mucho sentido, pero cuando llamas a algo como `User.new(params[:user])`,  podría venir en el request un parámetro no permitido, pero que sin embargo existe en tu modelo `User` (por ejemplo, en caso que existiera, un `admin: true`).
Ahora, lo mismo con strong parameters sería `User.new(usuario_params)`, donde sólo agregará los parámetros del request previamente permitidos/requeridos.
Para efectos de tu problema, podrías hacer:

```
Contrato.exists?(codigo: params[:user][:contrato])
```

y sería exactamente lo mismo.

Comment: listo, ya edité la pregunta, tengo una duda, porque usuario_params y no params solo? disculpa es que soy un completo noob en rails

Comment: @AndrésUcero ya edité la pregunta aclarando lo que me preguntas, pero no supe si mi respuesta resolvió tu problema.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, el params parece un hash anidado. Sin embargo, tu respuesta me salvó la vida jaja